# Why is `minLengh` not validating a missing property in JSON Schema?

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am trying to validate a json schema for my object.
But If else is not getting executed for my object.
So here in this example I want to check if Sale description is there when Sale service is 'Y'
(Note, I want to execute if else for object inside object) because saleScheduling is inside Sale object.

```
  "Sale":{
   "type":"object",
   "properties":{
      "SaleScheduling":{
         "type":"object",
         "properties":{
            "SaleDescription":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "SaleService":{
               "type":"string",
               "minLength":1,
               "enum":[
                  "Y",
                  "N"
               ]
            }
         },
         "if":{
            "properties":{
               "SaleService":{
                  "const":"Y"  //if this is Y, SaleDescription should be present
               }
            }
         },
         "then":{
            "properties":{
               "SaleDescription":{
                  "minLength":1
               }
            }
         },
         "else":{
            "properties":{
               "SaleDescription":{
                  
               }
            }
         },
         "required":[
            "SaleService"
         ]
      }
   },
   "required":[
      "SaleScheduling"
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make a property required using JSON Schema, you need to use the `required` keyword. Your subschema in the `else`...

```
{
  "properties":{
    "SaleDescription":{
      "minLength":1
    }
}
```

This will only apply `minLength` if the property `SalesDescription` exists. If it does not exist, it will not cause an error. This is how applicability works on JSON Schema. `properties` applies subschemas to an object based on the keys. `{ "minLength": 1 }` is itself a subschema, which is applied to a location in the instance.

This is an example of an X/Y problem. Your `if/then` is working correctly, but the `then` subschema isn't doing what you expect.

Comment: In order to help debugging JSON Schema, you can set any subschema to `false` to see if that subschema is used or not. `false` will cause validation to fail, but the subschema has to be applied.

Comment: Could you provide more information about setting subschema to false and how to debug the same.- Relequestual

Comment: For example, `"properties": {
    "SaleDescription": false
  }` would mean any value of `SaleDescription` will cause validation to fail. Live demo: https://jsonschema.dev/s/v8erZ

Comment: Or, even `"then": false`. `true` and `false` are valid schema values! =]

Comment: Can we apply if else condition based on the values from outside the object?

Comment: No. You can nest validation checks downwards, but you can't "see" upwards in the structure

Comment: Could you please help me in solving this issue @Relequestual (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64258202/how-to-validate-a-object-based-on-the-value-of-root-object-in-json-schema)